# How to replace symbol ' * ' with ' .* ' in matlab expression?

Tags: matlab

I have a long expression & I need to replace all multiplication symbols `' * '` with element-by-element multiplication symbols `' .* '` in it. It takes too long to do it by hand. Is there an easy way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Cntrl+F? find and replace tool that at least almost al windows application has...

Comment: It's often useful to load your Matlab project in another IDE, like Eclipse, which can do regexp search and replace.

Comment: Why do you want to replace `*` with `.*`? I assume you are aware that `[1 2] * [1;2]` is not equal to `[1 2] .* [1;2]` (it will actually error).

Answer (score 0):

I think that `Ctrl + H` is what you look for.

Comment: Is there any way to do it automaticaly within the function?

Comment: I guess you my call `times` then, but I'm not quite sure that it's gonna be **automatic** in the perspective you give to the term!

Comment: Ok, if I'm going to use Ctrl+H way, there is another problem. Matlab cannot display a whole expression for me, it says "Output truncated. Text exceeds maximum line length of 25,000 characters for Command Window display". So I cant use Ctrl+H, what do I do now?

Comment: Yeah, I know, but how cat ih help if a cant see the full output?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do two points.

1. I would do the replacement with a regular expression. like `regexprep('\.?*\*','.*')` that will take into account if there is already a `.` before.
2. The way to do it. The program [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) would would be perfect to do it. But you could as well do it in Matlab - loop over all files and replace the text.

Keep in mind that matlab will not be aware of the changes till it rehashes the files. Meaning you can not use the replaced functions immediatly.

Comment: Thanks alot bdecaf, its very helpfull. Also I have found this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19217-sym2str.

Comment: Oh - you didn't specify it was the output of a symbolic calculation. but it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

To do it programatically you should use a regular expression replacement:

```
>> str = 'x * y .* z';
>> regexprep(str, '\.?\*', '.*')
ans =
x .* y .* z
```

The regular expression `\.?\*` means "match all strings that are 0 or 1 dots (`\.?`) followed by the multiplication symbol (`\*`), i.e. it matches the strings `'.*'` and `'*'`, and replaces both of them with `'.*'`.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab has a builtin function (I think that it's in all installs) to do this: [`vectorize`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vectorize.html). The Symbolic Toolbox uses this function. It will also convert `^` and `/` to the element-wise equivalents too. Its based on [`strrep`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) and [`strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) which are join going to be faster than Matlab's slow regular expression implementation. type `edit vectorize` in the command window to see the brief code, which you could easily copy and modify for your needs.